# php cURL returning an empty string? What should I missing?

Tags: php

I have tried a lot of things but getting empty string. see the code below

```
<?php

    $_POST['bn_code'] = "YQkrqxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $code = isset($_POST['bn_code']) ? $_POST['bn_code'] : "";
    $cId = "rtywt7ezn9cror1ssb7axxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $rURL = "https://mycloudfish.com/";

   $fields = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code' , 'code' => $code, 'client_id' => $cId, 'client_secret' => 'eKJZKxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');


    $url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token';
    $fields_string  = "";
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
     $json = json_encode($result);
    echo $json;
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: If the API is returning JSON, you don't need to re-encode it.

Comment: What is `$rURL` for? Yuo never use it.

Comment: You can replace the `foreach` loop with `$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);`

Comment: It shouldn't cause a problem, but you're setting the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option twice.

Comment: You can also set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to `$fields` and `curl` will convert it automatically.